# mongoe's findOne method nether executes nor fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve data from mongodb through nodejs mnogdb-native driver. `mongod`console indicates that connection succeed. Unfortunately, after retrieving collection and logging message 'before findOne' to the console nothing happened. It's looks like the`findOne` method never returns.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
    config = require('./config');

var UserProvider = function() {
    this.db = new mongo.Db('chatbox', 
        new mongo.Server(config.mongoServer, config.mongoPort, {auto_reconnect: true}), {});
    this.db.open(function() {});
};

UserProvider.prototype.getCollection = function(callback) {
    this.db.collection('users', function(error, collection) {
    if (error) {
        callback(error);
    }
    else {
        callback(null, collection);
    }
    });
};

UserProvider.prototype.validateUser = function(username, password, callback) {
    this.getCollection(function(error, collection) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error');
            callback(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log('before findOne');
            collection.findOne({login: username, password: password}, function(error, item){
                console.log('done');
                if (error) {
                    callback(error);
                }
                else {
                    callback(null, item != null);
                }
            });
        }   
    });
};

module.exports = UserProvider;
```

Can anybody point me to the probable problem point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code that would use your code:

```
var myProvider = require('yourcode').UserProvider;

myProvider.validateUser('me','pwd', function(error, success) {
  console.log("Success: " + success);
});
```

When I get to `myProvider.validateUser`, am I guaranteed that `this.db.open()` has returned? Normally, this whole thing is sequential. But in Node.JS, that `db.open()` is not blocking. So the call goes out to the DB and then the code keeps running, so you actually have a race condition here.

Comment: Yes, I've already realized that, but thanks anyway. I was newbie into event driven world, so I haven't seen obvious things..

Answer (score 2):

A poke in the dark really - but try adding a console.log into the callback for `db.open`.

If that line does not show up before `'before findOne'` then most likely the issues is simply that the DB connection is not open.

Comment: Yes, that was an issue. I've found that approach at _mongo-node blog tutorial_ and no one post report about problems. That is strange ...